# jquery click & get value of attributes of a href

Tags: jquery, attributes, click, listener

How can I access seq value in a href, when I click thye link?

```
/* Add a listner to Group buttons */
    $('a.preActNav').click(function() { 
        alert(this.seq)
    });   



    <li><a href="#preclose4" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-d" data-transition="none" seq='1' class="preActNav"  ID="preActNavA">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#preclose4" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-d" data-transition="none" seq='2' class="preActNav"  ID="preActNavB">B</a></li>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Like this:

```
alert($(this).attr('seq'));
```

---

Although it may be better to put `seq` as another data element:

```
<li><a href="#preclose4" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-d" data-transition="none" data-seq='1' class="preActNav"  ID="preActNavA">A</a></li>
```

So then you can do:

```
alert($(this).data('seq'));
```

---

Comment: I saw this data stuff in HTML 5, but did not realize it's power!

Comment: @bob -- it is so very very powerful :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('a.preActNav').click(function() { 
        alert($(this).attr('seq'));
        //To get href
        alert(this.href);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: $(this).attr()? http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
$('a.preActNav').click(function() {
   alert($(this).attr('seq'));
});
```

you need to use $(this) jquery selector instead

Answer (score 1):

you can either use this code:

```
 $('.item').click(function(){

        console.log($(this).attr("name"));

    });
```

or

```
$('.item').on('click', () => {

    console.log($(".item.active").attr("name"));

});
```