# Pull value from drop-down menu into an API url

Tags: jquery, api

I am using an API that show information based on the two letter character code of each state. The states are in a drop down menu that looks like the following. I am trying to get the value and make it a variable called state that changes depending on which state is selected using jQuery.

```
                 <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
                 <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
                 <li><a href="campsitepg2.html" value="AL">Alabama</a></li>
                 <li><a href="campsitepg2.html" value="AK">Alaska</a></li>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I know it can be hard to come up with the right keywords for searching, but pls do try before posting a new question. I just tried "jquery clicked attribute" and turned up many answers here with code you can use, for eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519423/jquery-how-to-get-attribute-of-an-element-when-using-the-click-event/7519435, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625667/jquery-click-get-value-of-attributes-of-a-href, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205411/get-value-of-an-attribute-of-the-clicked-element ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery - How to get attribute of an element when using the 'click' event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519423/jquery-how-to-get-attribute-of-an-element-when-using-the-click-event)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```js
$("#dropdown1 li").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var state = $(this).find("a").attr("value");
  console.log(state);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
   <li><a href="campsitepg2.html" value="AL">Alabama</a></li>
   <li><a href="campsitepg2.html" value="AK">Alaska</a></li>
 </ul>
```